# determining the character set of a table / database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, collation

What T-SQL command can be run to find character set of a table or database in SQL Server?

edit:
Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)

Comment: Run SQL Server Management Studio and run `Select @@Verion` to check the version of SQL Server.

Comment: Refer `DATABASEPROPERTYEX` and `SERVERPROPERTY`

Answer (score 30):

You can check the version using

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
```

It it's 9.00 or greater, you can check the collation of a column using

```
SELECT collation_name FROM sys.columns 
WHERE name = 'column name'
AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table name');
```

And for the database using

```
SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'database name';
```

If it's < 9.0 then you're using SQL Server 2000 or lower. For 2000 I believe you can check similar columns (e.g. `syscolumns.collationid` for columns).

Comment: This works well for me; note the `collation_name` can tell you which "code page" is being used, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5039321/1175496). For example if the `collation_name` value is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", note that:

 > CP1 stands for Code Page 1252

Answer (score 16):

The character set depends on the data type of a column. You can get an idea of what character sets are used for the columns in a database as well as the collations using this SQL:

```
select data_type, character_set_catalog, character_set_schema, character_set_name, collation_catalog, collation_schema, collation_name, count(*) count
from information_schema.columns
group by data_type, character_set_catalog, character_set_schema, character_set_name, collation_catalog, collation_schema, collation_name;
```

If it's using the default character set, the character_set_name should be iso_1 (ISO 8859-1) for the char and varchar data types.  Since nchar and nvarchar store Unicode data in UCS-2 format, the character_set_name for those data types is UNICODE.

Answer (score 11):

To check the Collation of SQL Server run this in SQL Server Management Studio (put your database name in the appropriate place)

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DatabaseNameGoeshere', 'Collation') DatabaseCollation;
```

***Note that Collation settings can be set each level***

Server

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')  as ServerCollation
```

Database

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DatabaseNameGoeshere', 'Collation') DatabaseCollation;
```

Column (SQL Svr 2005 or higher)

```
Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Columns.COLLATION_NAME
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Column (lower than SQL Svr 2005)

```
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM syscolumns
WHERE OBJECT_ID IN 
(
    SELECT OBJECT_ID
    FROM sysobjects
    WHERE type = 'U'
    AND name = 'TableNameGoesHere'
)
AND name = 'ColumnNameGoesHere'
```

Comment: I receive null as the response. What does it mean?

Comment: Did you put the appropriate database name in the query?

Comment: `sys.columns` and `sys.objects` are not valid < SQL Server 2005, I think maybe you have those two backwards.

Comment: found a link with some official information on this (attention: for sql server 2012): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230914.aspx