# Inserting special characters (greater/less than or equal symbol) into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, unicode, nvarchar

I am trying to insert `≤` and `≥` into a symbol table where the column is of type `nvarchar`.

Is this possible or are these symbols not allowed in SQL Server?

Comment: Add the `N` prefix if this is not a standard character in your default collation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make it work, **prefix the string with `N`**

```sql
create table symboltable 
(
  val nvarchar(10)
)

insert into symboltable values(N'≥') 

select *
from symboltable
```

[image]

**Further Reading**:

- [You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114081311/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/239530/en-us)
- [Why do some SQL strings have an 'N' prefix?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150208024547/http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html)

Comment: anyway, without your downvote I wouldn't get the correct answer. That makes me do some research. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks. Completely forgot about the N prefix.

Comment: How it would work for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253235/how-to-use-if-else-statement-to-update-or-create-new-xml-node-entry-in-sql Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To add to gonzalo's answer, both the *string literal* and the *field* need to *support unicode characters*.

#### String Literal

Per Marc Gravell's answer on [What does N' stands for in a SQL script ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14353311/1366033):

> `'abcd'` is a literal for a `[var]char` string, occupying 4 bytes memory, and using *whatever code-page the SQL server is configured for*.
>    `N'abcd'` is a literal for a `n[var]char` string, occupying 8 bytes of memory, and using UTF-16.

Where the `N` prefix stands for "*National*" Language in the SQL-92 standard and is used for representing unicode characters.  For example, in the following code, any unicode characters in the basic string literal are first encoded into SQL Server's "code page":

[image: <code>SELECT '≤' AS ['≤'], N'≤' AS [N'≤']</code>]

> **Aside**: You can [check your code page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7321159/1366033) with the following SQL:
>
> ```
> SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('dbName', 'Collation') AS dbCollation;
> SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY( 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' , 'CodePage' ) AS [CodePage];
> ```
>
> The default is [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which only [contains these 256 characters](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ansi.asp)

#### Field Type

Once the values are capable of being *passed*, they'll also need to be capable of being *stored* into a [column that supports unicode types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), for example:

- `nchar`
- `nvarchar`
- `ntext`

**Further Reading**:

- [Why do we need to put N before strings in Microsoft SQL Server?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/155859/87466)
- [What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10025032/1366033)
- [You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114081311/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/239530/en-us)
- [Why do some SQL strings have an 'N' prefix?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150208024547/http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html)