# Is there any difference between OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#t1') and OBJECT_ID(N'TEMPDB..#t1')

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We can check if `#t1` exists using `OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#t1')`.

But I have also seen `OBJECT_ID(N'TEMPDB..#t1')` many times.

I have searched for that but didn't get any answer.Is there any real difference between them?

If there is any difference then which one to use?

Comment: I think your qustion related to `N`  and here is the answer..http://stackoverflow.com/a/14353275/1460657

Comment: Thanks Anant I got it.This post has explained me in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,
In `OBJECT_ID(N'TEMPDB..#t1')` -

> "**N**" is used to specify a unicode string.

Second thing, both the syntax will work, but it depends on your requirement.

**PS**: `N'` means - sending unicode charcters.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is:

```
OBJECT_ID ( '[ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] 
  object_name' [ ,'object_type' ] )
```

Arguments

- `' object_name '`

  Is the object to be used. object_name is either varchar or nvarchar. ***If object_name is varchar, it is implicitly converted to nvarchar***. Specifying the database and schema names is optional.
- `' object_type '`

  Is the schema-scoped object type. object_type is either varchar or nvarchar. If object_type is varchar, it is implicitly converted to nvarchar. For a list of object types, see the type column in sys.objects (Transact-SQL).

> Using **`N`** will represent a string as nvarchar.

Answer (score 0):

The first: `OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#t1')` use varchar notation, the second: `OBJECT_ID(N'TEMPDB..#t1')` use nvarchar notation.

But the behaviour is the same