# MsSql Grammar quoteString don't auto add 'N'

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I use Laravel 5.8 to insert row to MsSQL database

```
Model::insert([
  'name' => '中文字'
]);
```

The output SQL is

```
insert into table_name (name) values ('中文字')
```

But it's miss N char before string character.
How to set N before string character by auto. Like this

```
insert into table_name (name) values (N'中文字')
```

Comment: Have you tried `INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES ('N中文字')`

Comment: Seems there is some confusion as to where the N should be, this isn't adding the N to the string, but  a prefix to the string to show it's unicode ([What does N' stands for in a SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353238/what-does-n-stands-for-in-a-sql-script-the-one-used-before-characters-in-ins) I think shows what they mean)

Comment: You should probably log an Issue with the Laravel project on Github. Seems like a bug given that the SQLServer grammar implementation uses nvarchar datatype for all string columns.

Comment: Is this causing real issues? It'd be a strange oversight for a major framework. Doesn't Laravel use prepared statements and bound parameters?