# Insert greater/less than or equal symbol into db2 table column

Tags: jakarta-ee, db2

my clients copy and paste greater or less than symbol from Microsoft Word into my Java web application. I use IBM DB2 database. But the symbol shows in empty squeare in my select result.

What have I tried?
[Inserting greater/less than or equal symbol into SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028594/inserting-greater-less-than-or-equal-symbol-into-sql-server-database)

I tried above link, insert some value but it didn't insert value.

I thought I can replace that sign with >=  but I don't want to struggle. So how can I achieve this problem?

Comment: `INSERT INTO TABLE (column1) VALUES ('<'),('>')` works just fine for me. Maybe you should try posting some real details (the code point that's failing, some app code, and database details including version, platform, codepage) about the problem.

Comment: Greater than equal symbol, sorry for my  wrong title

Comment: OK, but you'll still need to post a bunch more details.

Comment: You need to know how your database was created and what character set it is using.  If you did not create it with a character set that supports that symbol then you need to insert a CLOB or a BLOG column to support it.