# Detect UNICODE characters that are not ASCII in table

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ascii, sql-server-2014, nvarchar

I have the following table:

```
Select
   name,
   address,
   description
from dbo.users
```

I would like to search all this table for any characters that are UNICODE but not ASCII. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking to return the characters themselves or only identify the records with such characters? @johnnybell has answered already for the latter case.

Comment: @shree.pat18 just the records will do ...some sort of pointer so I can find the "guilty parties"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to determine if there are any characters in an `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` / `NTEXT` column that cannot be converted to `VARCHAR`, you need to convert to `VARCHAR` using the `_BIN2` variation of the collation being used for that particular column. For example, if a particular column is using `Albanian_100_CI_AS`, then you would specify `Albanian_100_BIN2` for the test. The reason for using a `_BIN2` collation is that non-binary collations will only find instances where there is at least one character that does not have any mapping at all in the code page and is thus converted into `?`. But, non-binary collations do not catch instances where there are characters that don't have a direct mapping into the code page, but instead have a "best fit" mapping. For example, the superscript 2 character, `²`, has a direct mapping in code page 1252, so definitely no problem there. On the other hand, it doesn't have a direct mapping in code page 1250 (used by the Albanian collations), but it does have a "best fit" mapping which converts it into a regular `2`. The problem with the non-binary collation is that `2` will equate to `²` and so it won't register as a row that can't convert to `VARCHAR`. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'²' COLLATE French_100_CI_AS); -- Code Page 1252
-- ²
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'²' COLLATE Albanian_100_CI_AS); -- Code Page 1250
-- 2

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'²' COLLATE Albanian_100_CI_AS)
WHERE  N'²' <> CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'²' COLLATE Albanian_100_CI_AS));
-- (no rows returned)

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'²' COLLATE Albanian_100_BIN2)
WHERE  N'²' <> CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'²' COLLATE Albanian_100_BIN2));
-- 2
```

Ideally you would convert back to `NVARCHAR` explicitly for the code to be clear on what it's doing, though not doing this will still implicitly convert back to `NVARCHAR`, so the behavior is the same either way.

**Please note** that only `MAX` types are used. Do not use `NVARCHAR(4000)` or `VARCHAR(4000)` else you might get false positives due to truncation of data in `NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns.

So, in terms of the example code in the question, the query would be (assuming that a `Latin1_General` collation is being used):

```
SELECT usr.*
FROM   dbo.[users] usr
WHERE  usr.[name] <> CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), usr.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2))
OR     usr.[address] <> CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), usr.[address] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2))
OR     usr.[description] <> CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), usr.[description] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find non-ASCII characters quite simply:

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, DESCRIPTION
FROM DBO.USERS
WHERE NAME != CAST(NAME AS VARCHAR(4000))
OR ADDRESS != CAST(ADDRESS AS VARCHAR(4000))
OR DESCRIPTION != CAST(DESCRIPTION AS VARCHAR(4000))
```

Comment: well it runs. Just need to create some text with pure unicode in it to put my mind at rest that it highlights problems

Comment: Thanks Johnny: `SELECT ('vsdǣf' = CAST('vsdǣf' AS VARCHAR(4000)))` ...works

Comment: This isn't going to check for ASCII; It's going to check for the database default encoding, which probably isn't ASCII. To see what it is, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7321208/2226988).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an inbuilt function for this as far as I can tell. A brute force approach is to pass each character to `ascii` and then pass the result to `char` and check if it returns '?', which would mean the character is out of range. You can write a UDF with the below code as reference, but I should think that it is a very inefficient solution:

```
    declare @i int = 1
    declare @x nvarchar(10) = N'vsdǣf'
    declare @result nvarchar(100) = N''

    while (@i < len(@x))
    begin
     if char(ascii(substring(@x,@i,1))) = '?'
       begin
         set @result = @result + substring(@x,@i,1)       
       end
     set @i = @i+1
    end       

    select @result
```