# Non ASCII colum name in mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8

Can I use UTF-8 names in column name on data base? Like example here:

```
$zapytaj = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `użytkownicy` = '$nazwaużytkownika' ");
```

This give me error:

> Unknown column 'użytkownicy' in 'where clause'

Can someone explain why this is not working?

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
+--------------------------+-------------
| Variable_name            | Value
+--------------------------+-------------
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4
| character_set_filesystem | binary
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4
| character_set_server     | latin1
| character_set_system     | utf8

mysql> SELECT COLUMN_NAME, HEX(COLUMN_NAME)
    FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = "so31349641";
+--------------+--------------------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  | HEX(COLUMN_NAME)         |
+--------------+--------------------------+
| id           | 6964                     |
| użytkownicy  | 75C5BC79746B6F776E696379 | -- Note the C5BC for ż
| hasło        | 686173C5826F             | -- and the C582 for ł
+--------------+--------------------------+
```

If I delete `` from użytkownicy I see this error:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�ytkownicy = 'xxx'' at line 1`
Maybe PHP file are don't have UTF8 coding? How to check this file in PHPStorm?

## `!SOLUTION!`

If You have this error just change mysql to PDO that should fix Your problem.

Comment: What charset are you using?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;`

Comment: @RickJames <code>CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `użytkownicy` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
 `hasło` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4</code>

Answer (score 1):

To answer your stated question, column names are utf8:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE information_schema.columns\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: COLUMNS
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `COLUMNS` (
  `TABLE_CATALOG` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COLUMN_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',           -- NOTE --
  `ORDINAL_POSITION` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `COLUMN_DEFAULT` longtext,
  `IS_NULLABLE` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DATA_TYPE` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMERIC_PRECISION` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMERIC_SCALE` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATETIME_PRECISION` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COLLATION_NAME` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COLUMN_TYPE` longtext NOT NULL,
  `COLUMN_KEY` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EXTRA` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PRIVILEGES` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COLUMN_COMMENT` varchar(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

To get to the root of the implied question ("Why does the query fail"), let's see

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
```

**Edit**

Well, something un-obvious going on.  This works for me:

```
mysql> create table so31349641 (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    użytkownicy varchar(24) NOT NULL, 
    hasło varchar(24) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

mysql> INSERT INTO so31349641 VALUES (1, 'a', 'b');

mysql> SELECT * FROM so31349641 WHERE użytkownicy = 'a';
+----+--------------+--------+
| id | użytkownicy  | hasło  |
+----+--------------+--------+
|  1 | a            | b      |
+----+--------------+--------+
```

This seems ordinary:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
+--------------------------+-------------
| Variable_name            | Value
+--------------------------+-------------
| character_set_client     | utf8
| character_set_connection | utf8
| character_set_database   | latin1
| character_set_filesystem | binary
| character_set_results    | utf8
| character_set_server     | latin1
| character_set_system     | utf8
```

Looking in the IS:

```
mysql> SELECT COLUMN_NAME, HEX(COLUMN_NAME)
    FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = "so31349641";
+--------------+--------------------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  | HEX(COLUMN_NAME)         |
+--------------+--------------------------+
| id           | 6964                     |
| użytkownicy  | 75C5BC79746B6F776E696379 | -- Note the C5BC
| hasło        | 686173C5826F             | -- and the C582 for ł
+--------------+--------------------------+
```

That is as I would expect it.

My char% values are different than yours, but I think we are both "OK" for this situation.

Try a SELECT on the information_schema similar to what I did.

Next, what is your client?  PHP?  Something else?  Perhaps the encoding is incorrect in the client.

(Rather than trying to use HTML tags in a Comment, Edit your original question with the added info.)

Comment: My client is MySQL 5.6.24 . I send this query via PHP file index.php to login.php via POST. In PHPMyAdmin Your query work for me too but at PHP file not working. Hex name are this same as Yours.

Comment: Find the code in PHPStorm that connects.  It may be (erroneously) using `latin1`.

Comment: `$zapytaj = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `so31349641` = '$nazwaużytkownika'");`

Comment: That's not the connect.  Also, you probably need to switch to the `mysqli_*` interface.  `mysql_*` was deprecated about the time ut8f was implemented; there may be a reason.

Comment: Yes You have right. I just use PDO so this fix for me. All working fine. Thanks for You Rick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like UTF-8 in SQL is not default, but tables/databases can be changed to be so.

Some potentially helpful links:

The mySQL documentation on charsets:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html

A SO question on determining the charset:
[determining the character set of a table / database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321159/determining-the-character-set-of-a-table-database)

On changing the charset: http://makandracards.com/makandra/2529-show-and-change-mysql-default-character-set

Hope this helps.

Comment: He's using utf8mb4 (full UTF-8 support), not utf8_general_ci, which mostly covers the Latin charset

Comment: Latin1 does not have `ż`.  Utf8 and utf8mb4 have it as hex `C5BC`.

Comment: @RickJames So what I should to do if I want use <code> ż </code> ??

Comment: Use utf8mb4 at all stages.  Variables, table definitions, client encoding, etc.