# What type of encoding is used in PHP code?

Tags: php, .net, encoding

I have a migration project PHP into .NET. In this application i have a problem faced is that type of encoding used in the PHP Code. In the database having values like

> ThÃ¼ringen, Baden-WÃ¼rttemberg, OberÃ¶sterreich

Which is encoded in the output of format both JSON, XML as

> Th\u00fcringen, Baden-W\u00fcrttemberg, Ober\u00f6sterreich

Respectively. How could I do in .net. What type of Encoding is used in the PHP Code.

Answer (score 2):

In your database it is stored as UTF-8. You can see this due to the Unicode letter \u00fc (ü) whose UTF-8 representation is `0xC3 0xB6`.

If you try to read `0xC3 0xB6` as ISO-8859-1, you will read the garbage `Ã¼` from your first word Thüringen instead, proving that it's UTF-8 (and that whatever is reading your database is incorrectly thinking it is ISO-8859-1)

In your JSON/XML output, PHP has converted your code to Unicode code points, but I think this is irrelevant to your problem.

Assuming you are having trouble reading from the database with .net, make sure the encoding you are using is UTF-8 with the database, and it should read your data without any issue.

Comment: For PHP it uses MYSQL. for migration I entirely convert database MySQl to MSSQL with same structure.

Comment: Ok, you may have converted your database using the wrong encoding. Take a look to see what encoding you are using with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321159/determining-the-character-set-of-a-table-database - make sure your target MSSQL tables are in UTF-8 !!!