# nvarchar string not accepting multi-lingual value

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF6.0 code-first.

Here is my model

```
public class Album
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int AlbumID

    [Required]
    public string AlbumName
}
```

This has generated a table in my SQL Server database like this:

```
AlbumID (PK, int, not null)
AlbumName (nvarchar(max), not null)
```

But when I enter the `AlbumName` in any language other than English, it neither throws an error, nor does the correct value get saved.

When I run the select query it returns `AlbumName` as

```
1 , ????? ?????
2 , ????? ?????
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: where are you running teh query?

Comment: in sql server for testing purpose

Comment: You mean in management studio? That likely has no way to work with foreign charsets because it is an admin tool only? Test it from your own code.

Comment: If you are entering the album names manually in SSMS make sure you include the N prefix.

Comment: Do some analyses on used [character sets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7321159/861716).

Comment: Have you tried to setup a SQL Profiler trace to catch the actual statement sent to SQL Server by EF?