# Find tables not utf8?

Tags: sql-server

I have an error that claims a table is not utf8, but I am not sure how to find the table in question.  There are thousands of tables.  Is there a way to show character set of all the tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [determining the character set of a table / database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321159/determining-the-character-set-of-a-table-database)

Comment: Unless you're using SQL Server 2019 (preview), then none of your tables will be UTF-8. Before then, SQL Server did not support UTF-8.

Comment: Where is this error message coming from?

Comment: For reference to my above comment: [Introducing UTF-8 support in SQL Server 2019 preview](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2018/12/18/introducing-utf-8-support-in-sql-server-2019-preview/)