# SQL Server Like Query not case sensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Query

```
SELECT  * 
from Table_2  
WHERE  name like ('Joe');
```

Output

```
1   100 Joe
2   200 JOE
3   300 jOE
4   400 joe
```

Why is it not case sensitive?

Comment: Unrelated but: `LIKE` does not make any sense if you don't use a wildcard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem:

> Query not case sensitive

Cause:  Column 'Name' has a case-insensitive (`CI`) collation.

Solution: You have to use a `CS` collation: `SELECT * FROM fn_helpcollations() WHERE description LIKE N'%case-sensitive%'`.

Note: There is a database collation and column level collation. And, there is, also, a server level collation.

```
SELECT  DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS DatabaseCollation
/*
-- Sample output (my database)
DatabaseCollation
----------------------------
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
*/

SELECT  col.collation_name AS ColumnCollation
FROM    sys.columns col
WHERE   col.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Table_2') 
AND     col.name = N'Name'
/*
-- Sample output (my database)
ColumnCollation
----------------------------
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
*/
```

Simply changing database collation will **NOT** change the collation for existing user tables and columns:

> This statement does not change the collation of the columns in any
>   existing user-defined tables. These can be changed by using the
>   COLLATE clause of ALTER TABLE.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx)

After **changing database collation**, the output of above queries will be:

```
/*
DatabaseCollation -- changed
----------------------------
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
*/

/*
ColumnCollation -- no change
----------------------------
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
*/
```

and, as you can see the collation of column `Name` remains CI.

More, changing database collation will affect only the new created tables and columns.
Thus, changing database collation could generate strange results (in my *opinion*) because some `[N][VAR]CHAR` columns will be CI and the new columns will be CS.

Detailed solution #1: if just some queries for column `Name` need to be `CS` then I will rewrite `WHERE` clause of these queries thus:

```
SELECT  Name 
FROM    dbo.Table_2
WHERE   Name LIKE 'Joe' AND Name LIKE 'Joe' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

[image]

This will give a change to SQL Server to do an `Index Seek` on column `Name` (in there is an index on column `Name`). Also, the execution plan will include an implicit conversion (see `Predicate` property for `Index Seek`) because of following predicate `Name = N'Joe' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`.

Detailed solution #2: if all queries for column `Name` need to be CS then I will change the collation only for column `Name` thus:

```
-- Drop all objects that depends on this column (ex. indexes, constraints, defaults)
DROP INDEX IX_Table_2_Name ON dbo.Table_2

-- Change column's collation
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_2
ALTER COLUMN Name VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
-- Replace VARCHAR(50) with proper data type and max. length
-- Replace COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS with the right CS collation

-- Recreate all objects that depends on column Name (ex. indexes, constraints, defaults)
CREATE INDEX IX_Table_2_Name ON dbo.Table_2 (Name)

-- Test query
SELECT  Name 
FROM    dbo.Table_2
WHERE   Name LIKE 'Joe'
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want your query to be case sensitive on few occasions only, then you can try below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
where Col1 = 'abcdEfhG' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Just add **"COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS"** in front of the query.

Answer (score 1):

That is your DB is configured to be case insensitive.

In order to change this:

- Open **SSMSE**.
- **Right Click** on your DB and select **Properties**
- Select **Options** in the left pane.
- Change the value under **Collation** to the same value you are currently using, just with CS (Case sensitive) instead of CI (Case Insensitive)

For example, If you are using:

- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_**CI**_AS

Change it to:

- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_**CS**_AS

If you want to understand a bit more about collations, take a look at the accepted answer under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039211/what-does-collate-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-do) thread.

[image]

**Update:**
Please  Note that as @BogdanSahlean has noted this solution will work for newly created objects but not for existing tables and columns.
From MSDN:

> You can change the collation of any new objects that are created in a
>   user database by using the COLLATE clause of the ALTER DATABASE
>   statement. This statement does not change the collation of the columns
>   in any existing user-defined tables. These can be changed by using the
>   COLLATE clause of ALTER TABLE.

Comment: how can we turn it off?