# How to select data from table "Article" and "Tags"

Tags: sql

> Article(ArticleID,CategoryID,Title,Description,....)
>
> Tag(TagID,ArticleID,TagName)

```
Select Artilce.*
From Article,Tag
Where Article.ArticleID=Tag.ArticleID
      and Tag.TagName like N'%" + tag + "%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

I want to select all entries with the tag is # tag. I have written statements like this,but i  don't know it is right or not, or missing something?

Comment: `do not know right or not`? So what you got and what is your expected output?

Comment: I think to "group by", but statements was to long.

Comment: My statement did not return a correct result (0 rows).

Comment: Could you provide sample data on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?

Comment: Look on your query, i don't see any problem. But maybe it's come from your data.
Did you try to remove `COLLATE`? Refer to this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039211/what-does-collate-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-do

Comment: What dbms are you working with? Also, don't use implicit joins explicit joins are a part of ansi-sql for more then 20 years now.

Comment: Ok, thanks Manh Le and  Zohar Peled, I wrote the other statements and works well, I have seen mistakes, relations between the two tables is 1-n so will not be able to get the right result. :)