# equivalent for "COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL" in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, collate

SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE outpatients (
    lastupdatedby nvarchar(250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    quote_id decimal(11,0) NULL,
    customersite_ID decimal(11,0) NULL)
```

What's the equivalent for `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL` in snowflake?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039211/what-does-collate-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-do

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/collation.html

Answer (score 1):

it would seem you want ether `COLLATE 'en_ci_as'` or `COLLATE 'ci_as'` as the code page and latin1 parts do not appear to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Latin-1 is basically extended ASCII, according to https://kb.iu.edu/d/aepu.

I don't think you will get the exact same collation in Snowflake, but en-ci-as could be the closest one.