# PHP search using == and not case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a code in PHP and I want to use == operator to search only exact terms and also have the search not case sensitive. The first thing doesn't work when I change LIKE to ==.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('********','********','********');
mysql_select_db("********",$con);

function search_results($keywords){
    $returned_results = array(); 
    $where ="";

    $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$keywords);
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);

    foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
        $where .= "`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
        if($key != ($total_keywords -1)){
            $where .=" AND ";
        }
    }
    $results = "SELECT name, image_url, game_url, alt FROM search_games WHERE $where";
    $results_num = ($results =mysql_query($results))? mysql_num_rows($results):0;
    if($results_num === 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $returned_results[] = array(
        'name' => $results_row['name'],
        'image_url' => $results_row['image_url'],
        'game_url' => $results_row['game_url'],
        'alt' => $results_row['alt']
    );
}
        return $returned_results;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please start using `mysqli_` or `PDO` as `mysql_` is deprecated and removed in PHP7

Answer (score 2):

Use MySql [LOWER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function to perform incasesensitive search:

```
...

foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword) {
    $keyword = strtolower($keyword);
    $where .= " LOWER(`keywords`) LIKE '%$keyword%'";
    if ($key != ($total_keywords -1)) {
        $where .= " AND ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the foreach with the code below:

```
foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
    $keyword = strtoupper($keyword);
    $where .= "upper(`keywords`) = '$keyword'";
    if($key != ($total_keywords -1)){
        $where .=" AND ";
    }
}
```

The code above, makes the `$keyword` string to upper case and then in the sql query it compares it with the `upper(keywords)`, so they both are upper case when compared.

Sources:

- http://alvinalexander.com/sql/sql-select-case-insensitive-query-queries-upper-lower
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Comment: I use the solution with lower. This solution is practically the same, but there is wrong position of commas `upper(keywords)`, it should be upper(`keywords`). But = operator doesn't work.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks for the correction. I edited it. Does it work now?

Comment: The solution with lower works, but operator = doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean the operator = doesn't work? On which line of code?

Comment: (by the way in the correction there was deleted ` symbols)

Comment: $where .= "upper(`keywords`) LIKE '%$keyword%'"; I want to use = instead of LIKE.

Comment: Yes I undertood it. I have edited them. I also replaced the = with LIKE. What is not working?

Comment: I need to use = or == operator because I don't want to search by nonsense, because LIKE cause that it will search the substring. I want to search by exact phrase.

Comment: Oh I get it. Why doesn't = work? It should work (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871578/how-to-compare-strings-in-sql-ignoring-case)). Maybe you don't check it correctly? What are the results? Actually you shouldn't use % signs, see my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135492/discussion-between-thanasis-and-catchamouse).